# Sound not working at all

Tags: sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, alsa

After a bit of messing around including doing this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa; sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2

 sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop linux-image-

uname -r 

libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG 

cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'

whoami
```

no sound works anymore. The sound controller that is normally in the top right of the screen is now also gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ~/.config/pulse
```

wait ten seconds, then run this:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Should the approach above fail to correct the problem, you can try this next.

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ~/.config/pulse
```

wait 10 seconds, then reboot.

If that still did not help, please proceed...

Execute this command and reboot:

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```